# Are there more integer solutions to this system of equations?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, integers

Let $n>0$ and $b_1,b_2, \dots, b_n,b_{n+1},b_{n+2} >0$ as well as $c_1, \dots, c_n >0$ be positive integers.
We ask that $b_i < c_j$ for $i \in \{1,\dots,n+1\}$ and $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.
That is: "every $b_i$ is smaller than every $c_j$."
Find all solutions to the system of equations

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+2} b_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 = -1,
\quad\quad
\sum_{i=1}^{n+2}b_i-\sum_{i=1}^n c_i = 1.$$

Example:
$n=1$, $b_1=b_2=b_3=1$ and $c_1=2$ is a solution.
For $n=1$ Mathematica says this is the unique solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is $n=1$, $b_i=1 (i=1,\cdots,3)$, $c_1=2$.

*Proof*: Suppose there is a solution.  Let $x = \max(b_i,i=1,\cdots,n+2)$. Then:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+2}b_i \leq (n+2)x$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\geq n(x+1)$$

Hence, using the second equation:

$$1=\sum_{i=1}^{n+2}b_i - \sum_{j=1}^nc_j \leq (n+2)x – n(x+1) = 2x – n$$

So $1 \leq 2x–n$  implying $n \leq 2x-1\quad(A)$.

Also:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+2}b_i^2 \leq (n+2)x^2$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^n c_j^2\geq n(x+1)^2$$

Hence, using the first equation:

$$-1=\sum_{i=1}^{n+2}b_i^2 - \sum_{j=1}^n c_j^2 \leq (n+2)x^2-n(x+1)^2 = 2x^2-n(2x+1)$$

So, using (A):

$$-1\leq 2x^2 – (2x-1)(2x+1) = 1-2x^2$$

Since the $b_i$’s and therefore x are positive integers, this implies $x=1$ and therefore, from (A), $n=1$, from which we can infer $b_i=1 (i=1,\cdots,3)$ and $c_1=2$.